# Add form value to end of url - Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a input field that has the id #formValueId

```
<input id="formValueId" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email address" name="unsubemail">
```

I'm using this function here as well,

```
function addURL(element) {
$(element).attr('href', function(){
    return this.href + 'unsubscribe-complete?q=direct_unsubscribe&fn=Public_DirectUnsubscribeForm&id=IDSTRING&' + 'unsubscribeEmail';
});
}
```

I also created a variable like this,

```
var unsubscribeEmail = $("#formValueId").val();
```

at the end of my addURL function for return this.href line I'm adding the variable to the end of it and it works great but the url isn't passing the val(); it's just putting the var name at the end. what am I doing wrong here?

**+ 'unsubscribeEmail';**

Comment: _“what am I doing wrong here?”_ – you’re adding a _string value_ that contains the _text_ `unsubscribeEmail` …

Answer (score 1):

by using `'unsubscribeEmail'` you make it just string so use `unsubscribeEmail`  instead of `'unsubscribeEmail'`

```
function addURL(element) {
$(element).attr('href', function(){
    return this.href + 'unsubscribe-complete?q=direct_unsubscribe&fn=Public_DirectUnsubscribeForm&id=IDSTRING&' + unsubscribeEmail;
});
}
```

Comment: I'm getting IDSTRING&undefined now is that because it's not in a document ready function? looks l it's working just isn't passing the val to the url say's undefined a the end.

Comment: @gx2g better to use your code inside document ready .. and it works here http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sm9onvyh/  .. if it not work with you or give you undefined again  just update this demo with your related code and send it back to me

Comment: says the addURL is undefined i have the <a looking like this here with an onlick

Comment: <a href="/" id="myButton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:addURL(this)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;</a>

Comment: <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var unsubscribeEmail = $("#formValueId").val();
 addURL('a');

 function addURL(element) {
  $(element).attr('href', function(){
      return this.href + 'unsubscribe-complete?q=direct_unsubscribe&fn=Public_DirectUnsubscribeForm&id=IDSTRING&' + unsubscribeEmail;
  });
 }
});
 </script>

Comment: <a id="myButton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:addURL(this);"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;</a>

Comment: @gx2g its working but not on load .. its working wrap on head after jquery liberary include or wrap before </body> http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sm9onvyh/2/

Comment: @gx2g you can use it like this instead of onclick=   http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sm9onvyh/3/  this will work with you .. Note: id must be unique so don't use same id for more than one element